# When are pytest fixture generators continued and does the scope affect this?

Tags: python, pytest

My `tests` directory looks like this:

```
tests/
    conftest.py
    some_of_tests/
        conftest.py
        test_parts.py
        test_these_parts.py
    some_other_tests/
        conftest.py
        test_these_other_parts.py
```

I have a fixture in the `/tests/confest.py` that creates some test file, instantiates a database connection, then does some database cleanup:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def setup_db():
    try:
        generate_test_files()
        db = connect_to_db()
        yield db
    finally:
        # cleanup 
        print("Cleaning up session scoped fixture")
```

Within the `tests/some_tests/conftest.py`, I have another fixture that creates some files, creates a database table, then deletes those files:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='package')
def local_setup():
    try:
        generate_test_files()
        # do stuff with db
        yield db
    finally:
        delete_test_files()
        print("Cleaning up package scoped fixture")
```

I have my tests set up in such a way that I'd like the test files generated by `some_of_tests` to be cleaned up before running the tests in `some_other_tests`. I was expecting the fixtures in `some_of_tests` to continue and call `delete_test_files()` before running the tests in the `some_other_tests`, but when I run `pytest --capture=no tests`, I see:

```
Cleaning up session scoped fixture
Cleaning up package scoped fixture
```

*after all the tests have run*, and they are not in the order I expected. What am I misunderstanding and what is the best way to cleanup package scoped tests before running the next package of tests?

Also, I understand that `pytest` runs in alphabetical order. I am exploiting this to run the tests in the order I want them to. So pytest would run them like `some_of_tests/test_parts.py -> some_of_tests/test_these_parts.py -> some_other_tests/test_these_other_parts.py`

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue using the example you provided; package-scoped fixture is finalized before the session-scoped one.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. But what i concluded was you need to have `__init__.py` added to your tests so that they can be recognized as packages.
Else it will run the teardown for the test in the end and act like a session.

For ex:

```
system_test/
     - conftest.py
     - test_dir1/
          - __init__.py
          - conftest.py (here put scope as package)
          - test1.py
          - test2.py
     - test_dir2/
          - __init__.py
          - test1.py
          - test2.py
          - conftest.py (here put scope as package)
```

It works as expected.